# Taking advantage of move semantics in C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, vector, move-semantics

I have a problem where I want to store vectors of structs inside individual container class.

The problem is that while creating this container for these vectors, I waste resources because the vectors are copied; not moved. Why are the resources in the temporary returned by `create()` not transferred to local variable `master_data` in the main function?

Sample code that I assumed would work is presented below (and in coliru [HERE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84034da7154e2cc2)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Specific data struct
typedef struct DataA {
    DataA(): a(rand()), 
             b(rand()) {}
    int a,b;    
} DataA;

// Another specific data struct
typedef struct DataB {
    DataB(): c(rand()), 
             d(rand()) {}
    int c,d;
} DataB;

// Container of all relevant data
typedef struct Master {
    Master(const std::vector<DataA> &a, const std::vector<DataB> &b) : data_a(std::move(a)), data_b(std::move(b)) {}
    Master(const Master &rhs) : data_a(std::move(rhs.data_a)), data_b(std::move(rhs.data_b)) {}

    std::vector<DataA> data_a;
    std::vector<DataB> data_b;
} Master;


Master create() {
    std::vector<DataA> data_a(10);
    std::vector<DataB> data_b(10);

    printf("data_a address inside create()   : %p\n", (void*)data_a.data());
    printf("data_b address inside create()   : %p\n", (void*)data_b.data());

    return {data_a, data_b};
}


int main()
{  
    Master master_data(create());

    printf("data_a address outside create()  : %p\n", (void*)master_data.data_a.data());
    printf("data_b address outside create()  : %p\n", (void*)master_data.data_b.data());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The concepts is called "move **semantics**", not "move schematics".

Comment: __Paste__ code that you want to ask about, don't link to them. Also provide a [mcve] and a clear question statement. "Does this work?" is not a clear question statement, "Does line x have time complexity of Y?" is.

Comment: @PasserBy: I made edits to improve the question.

Comment: Implementing move semantics into copy constructor - won't work. `Master`'s constructor moves from parameters that are passed by value beforehand.

Comment: @LogicStuff, that was my mistake. I forgot/meant to add `&`'s for in the master's first constructor. I understand that when I pass by value, the old data will be lost.

Comment: Now the parameters are `const` and you cannot move from those because they cannot be modified. A move constructor would look like `Master(Master&& rhs)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
Master(const Master &rhs) : data_a(std::move(rhs.data_a)), data_b(std::move(rhs.data_b)) {}
```

the parameters are *constant*, which prevent them from being moved, since they are immutable.

Try using something like this instead:

```
Master(Master&& rhs) : data_a(std::move(rhs.data_a)), data_b(std::move(rhs.data_b)) {}
```

where I dropped `const` and enhanced your parameter with `&&`.

Similarly for the constructor, you would do:

```
Master(std::vector<DataA>&& a, std::vector<DataB>&& b) : data_a(std::move(a)), data_b(std::move(b)) {}
```

Last, but not least, you should modify your create function like so (otherwise you will get a compilation error about not being able to bind):

```
Master create() {
    ...
    return {std::move(data_a), std::move(data_b)};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor:

```
Master(const std::vector<DataA> &a, const std::vector<DataB> &b);
```

accepts the `a` and the `b` parameters as constant references. You have to define it to accept rvalue references as following:

```
Master(std::vector<DataA>&& a, std::vector<DataB>&& b);
```

But in this case you have to indicate that `data_a` and `data_b` inside the `create()` function may be moved:

```
Master create() {
    std::vector<DataA> data_a(10);
    std::vector<DataB> data_b(10);

    printf("data_a address inside create()   : %p\n", (void*)data_a.data());
    printf("data_b address inside create()   : %p\n", (void*)data_b.data());

    return { std::move(data_a), std::move(data_b) };
}
```